# Julia - How to conver DataFrame to Array?

Tags: arrays, dataframe, julia

I have a DataFrame containing only numerical values. Now, what I'd like to do is extract all the values of this DataFrame as an Array. How can I do this? I know that for a single column, if I do `df[!,:x1]`, then the output is an array. But how to do this for all the columns?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The shortest form seems to be:

```
julia> Matrix(df)
3×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.723835  0.307092
 0.02993   0.0147598
 0.141979  0.0271646
```

In some scenarios you might want need to specify the type such as `Matrix{Union{Missing, Float64}}(df)`

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the [`Tables`](https://github.com/JuliaData/Tables.jl) API for this, in particular the [`Tables.matrix`](https://tables.juliadata.org/stable/#Tables.matrix) function:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(x=rand(3), y=rand(3))
3×2 DataFrame
 Row │ x          y        
     │ Float64    Float64  
─────┼─────────────────────
   1 │ 0.33002    0.180934
   2 │ 0.834302   0.470976
   3 │ 0.0916842  0.45172

julia> Tables.matrix(df)
3×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.33002    0.180934
 0.834302   0.470976
 0.0916842  0.45172
```

Answer (score 3):

```
convert(Matrix, df[:,:])
```

Try this

Comment: Thanks, this does work. But I was wondering if there was a method on DataFrames.jl to do this directly, while having to explicitly convert it.

Comment: `convert` is not supported currently. Use `Matrix` constructor.